# Share SSH object to child process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to share a global ssh variable from parent process to child process using a multiprocessing package.
I have tried to use "Value" method but there is no proper ctype for ssh.

```
ssh = multiprocessing.Value(gw_manager.openSSH())
```

any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried pickle?

Comment: What is `gw_manager` (and what is returned by `gw_manager.openSSH()`?)

Comment: gw_manager handles the connections with the server, gw_manager.openSSH() return open ssh object.

Comment: If the ssh object is not picklable (which is all likelihood it shouldn't be) then your only option is to use a multiprocessing manager to register `type(gw_manager.openSSH)` and return that instead